# Something changes files name in Windows when there are whitespaces (Windows Shell arguments)

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, windows-shell

I am developing an application based on C# WPF.

This application uses system register to capture the Explorer Context Menu actions. In other words: the Explorer Context Menu presents an additional Item customized for my application, a bit like NotePad++ (see image 1).

I click on the right button on a file and my application is launched correctly. Naturally, the file name is passed to the application as argument% 1 from the command line. The image 2 shows how I configured the registers for the context menu.

The problem is that if the file name does not contain spaces, everything is fine. If instead it contains spaces, I find the file name in capital letters and truncated.

---

#### Case 1 OK

File name: `dummy.txt`

String captured in %1: `dummy.txt`

---

#### Case 2 KO

File name: `paths - Copia.txt`

String captured in %1: `PACE0~1.TXT`

---

In the following two examples, the first correct and working, the second is the scenario in which I have the problems described.

---

> Image 1

[image]

> Image 2

[image]

Does anyone know a way to avoid this?

#### Footnotes

*Unfortunately I know very little about the Windows system and this is causing me a lot of headaches. I have no idea what the cause of the problem might be.*

*Keep in mind that I may have misplaced the question: I myself am doubtful that I have provided the information necessary to solve the problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and change the registry entries to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Polito\Kyactus\Kyactus.exe" "%1"` -- enclose both the path to the program and the `%1` in quotes, but for each use a different pair.